# Hyperref links in TOC point to wrong location when using titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, titletoc

I have modified the formatting of subsections in the toc, so that they appear in one line instead of separate lines. For this i used the titletoc package. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}%
    [3.8em]%
    {\small\itshape}%
    {\hyperlink{subsection.\thecontentslabel}{\thecontentslabel}\ }%
    {}%
    {\ \thecontentspage}%
    [,\ ]%
    [.]%

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\clearpage
\section{Another Section}
\end{document}
```

This was very easy, but there are two problems:

1. The subsection label is not included in the link. This is already fixed in the MWE with the help of the answer to this question: [Common style for global TOC, LOF, LOT and titletoc partial TOCs (with hyperref & caption)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100301/common-style-for-global-toc-lof-lot-and-titletoc-partial-tocs-with-hyperref)
2. The link to the section following the modified subsections points to the wrong location. In the MWE the link of '1.2 Another Section' points to '1.1.1 Subsection'.

I have not found a solution to the second problem. I have experimented with `\phantomsection` without any success. I have read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78980/how-to-emulate-titletoc-with-tocloft) that titletoc has some incompatibilities with hyperref and tried to implement the same behavior with the tocloft package. I managed to get something similar, but not quite right. The tocloft approach seems to be so much more convenient, if the links would work properly.

On a sidenote: The document i want to apply this to is rather large and is typeset with the [classicthesis style](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/).

I would appreciate any tips or solutions to this problem.

Comment: I'm using texlive 2012 (via official ppa backport), `scrbase 2012/05/15 v3.11 KOMA-Script package` and `titletoc 1.6`. Your code is working like a charm without any problem or wrong linking.

Comment: @Pouya: Really? My output does **not** provide the desired linking. I wonder, if `titletoc` really sets a `\hypertarget` command at all in the corresponding sections, subsections etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I think so... Maybe I haven't understand the question perfectly, so [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564961/temp.pdf) is my pdf. Tell me if I got it wrong.

Comment: @Pouya: I believe you ;-) I think, the problem is due to some clash between `titletoc` and the KOMA classes

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I just checked, the problem remains when using the standard article document class. The result just doesn't look so nice....

Comment: @CFL: Yes, I checked just some seconds ago. It is definitely some `titletoc` problem!

Comment: @Pouya, I am using MikTeX 2.9, titletoc 2011/12/15 v1.6, KOMA-Script v3.12, and hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m. As the problem remains without KOMA script it must be MikTeX vs. TeXLive. What hyperref version do you have?

Comment: @CFL: I am using a newer version of TeXLive, but titletoc is still that old, KOMA v3.12, but it is not connected to KOMA itself

Comment: Listing files, I have these values in my log file: `hyperref.sty 2012/05/13 v6.82q`, `scrbook.cls 2012/05/15 v3.11`, `titletoc.sty 2011/12/15 v1.6`.

Comment: I just downgraded to hyperref v6.82q and the links are correct. It seems to be a clash between titletoc and the newer version of hyperref (v6.83m). will add this as an answer. thank you both for checking.

Comment: [Take a look at this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162846/), it seems like it might provide you with a decent workaround, or some ideas at least...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a workaround, (or hack ;-)), it seems, that `titletoc` screws up the hyperlinks of sections for some reason I have not figured out so far.

I redefined the `\section` command to manually set the hyperlinks and a dummy hypertarget right after the section starts. It works for `\section{}` and `\section[]{}` commands, but not for `\section*{}`, but this writes no entry to the `TOC`, so this is something you can live with(???).

I also used `\usepackage{classicthesis}`, which seems to come before `titletoc`, otherwise the toc style is not used.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linktoc=all]{hyperref} % Normally last!!!
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{titletoc}


\titlecontents*{subsection}%
    [3.8em]%
    {\small\itshape}%
    {\phantomsection\hyperlink{subsection::\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{\thecontentslabel}\ }%
    {}%
    {\ \thecontentspage}%
    [,\ ]%
    [.]%




\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\section@noopt}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardSection[\protect\hyperlink{section::\thesection}{#1}]{#1}%
\phantomsection%
\hypertarget{section::\thesection}{}% Empty target
}%

\newcommand{\section@opt}[2][]{%
\LaTeXStandardSection[\protect\hyperlink{section::\thesection}{#1}]{#2}%
\phantomsection%
\hypertarget{section::\thesection}{}% Empty target
}%


\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\section@opt}{\section@noopt}%
}%
\makeatother    

\begin{document}



\tableofcontents 

\chapter{First}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\newpage
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\clearpage
\section{Another Section}%
\clearpage
\section[Yet Another Section]{Yet another section with a different short title}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}
\subsection{Yet another another subsection}%
\chapter{Next chapter}
\section[Yet Another Section]{Yet another section with a different short title}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}
\subsection{Yet another another subsection}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that was quick. This works, but it produces some warnings: `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string` I guess i can live with that as I prefer to keep the current version of hyperref.

Comment: While the MWE is fixed with your code, it does not fix the document i am working on. There must be an additional problem elsewhere. However, that will take a while to look into, so i guess it is down to v6.82q for now...

Comment: @CFL: Could you perhaps post your more elaborate document or at least the relevant portions of it, so that I can look for some solution. I suspect, that linking to the toc requires some redefinition of the other sectioning commands as well -- I already feared that this could be an issue. You could also contact Heiko Oberdiek in TeX.SX chat.

Comment: that is a very generous offer, thank you. For now I have not encountered any new problems by using the older version of hyperref. As that is fixing the problem, I want to spare you looking through my messy code. Anyway, a real fix could only be worked out when looking into the internals of titletoc and hyperref, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be a clash between titletoc v1.6 and the current version of hyperref v6.83m. Downgrading to hyperref v6.82q solves the problem. However, using the outdated version of hyperref might produce other complications.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed in version 2.11 of titletoc; see the changelog at
https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec

When I switched to this version of titletoc, it solved this problem for me.