# titletoc: Hyperref section number and page number

Tags: hyperref, titletoc

Using titletoc, is it possible to not only hyperlink the section name, but also the section number and the page number?

**Solution:**

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100413/71253

Comment: ues \usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

Comment: Thanks. Page numbers do now reference, but not the section numbers.

Comment: In a standard setup (without using `titletoc`) the references are enabled if you use the proposition made by touhami. If this is not the case, you show us a MWE

Comment: Thank you. The solution was provided in the answer above. I'm sorry I did not find this thread earlier.